# How redirect all pages to 'https' using htaccess and Wordpress with a subdomain?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I need to redirect all "http" requests to "https". I did something like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule (.*) https://example.com.br/site/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It seems work appropriately, but this is not loading files. Files should be opened using the url:

```
https://example.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/briefing/css/style.css
```

but instead, the page try to load:

```
https://example.com.br/site/css/style.css
```

"https://" does not appear in Browser. I am using Wordpress, the site is inside a "site" folder. My big problem is because I have a ajax request and had the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://exemple.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/briefing/includes/loopHandler.php?numPosts=3&pageNumber=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com.br' is therefore not allowed access.
```

My htacess file begins with:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace your `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
```

by the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
```

---

The `HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto` you currently using only checks if a proxy forwarded non https traffic. This is not really related to your problem. You need a general check if incoming requests are not https requests: `%{HTTPS} !on`.

Comment: Thank you, but the files are not loading appropriately, still trying to load with "http"

Comment: Have you enabled mod_rewrite?

Comment: yes, seems that it worked but still haing problems with wordpress file loading. Files should be opened using the url: https ://example.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/briefing/css/style.css but instead, the page try to load: https ://example.com.br/site/css/style.css

Answer (score 0):

You may can try that:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mysite.com/my-sub-domain/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Hi, seems that it worked but still haing problems with wordpress file loading. Files should be opened using the url:

https://example.com.br/site/wp-content/themes/briefing/css/style.css
but instead, the page try to load:

https://example.com.br/site/css/style.css

Comment: Is you variables in DB correct ? Try yo determine if `site` and `home` records in wp_options table point in your root URL of your web site installation

Answer (score 0):

Keep your rules like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site/

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com.br%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /site/index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

- Then do make sure your home and site URLs in WP's permalink settings also has `https://` URLs.